# How to detect a tab bar being double tapped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

Using NSNotification within Tabbar DidSelectItem like so to call a scroll up method.

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"homeScrollUp" object:nil];
}
```

It works nicely but how can i detect it by tapping index tab 0 twice for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something link this? Make sure you invalidate the timer when you're cleaning up the class.

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
   NSUInteger indexOfTab = [[theTabBar items] indexOfObject:item];
   if(indexOfTab==0) {
      self.chosenIndexTapped++
   }
  self.tabPressTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:smallTimeToAllowTap
                                                              target:self
                                                            selector:@selector(handleRecognisedTap)
                                                            userInfo:nil
                                                             repeats:NO];
  [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.tabPressTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes]; 
}

-(void)handleRecognisedTap {
    if(self.chosenIndexTapped>1){
        //Scroll to top
    }
    self.chosenIndexTapped = 0 //Reset the taps on your chosen index
}
```

Comment: What is `self.chosenIndexTapped++` and `self.tabPressTimer` and `smallTimeToAllowTap`

Comment: self.chosenIndexTapped is an integer that you increase on tap of index. self.tabPressTimer is an NSTimer. Both of these you will have to define as properties in your class. smallTimeToAllowTap is an NSTimeInterval that you'll have to create to allow for the time of a second tap maybe something like 0.5

Comment: thanks, and what is `  [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.salesRequestTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes]; 
` for ?

Comment: It's just to add the timer to the current run loop so that it will go off

Comment: self.salesRequestTimer is a number?

Comment: Thanks, how should I create the property for the integer? I did NStimer like so: `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *tabPressTimer;`

Comment: i ended up doing this `@property(nonatomic, assign) int chosenIndexTapped;
`

Comment: That'll do what you need